# Is .git folders in vendor folder is safe to delete?

Tags: php, git, doctrine-orm, laravel

My Laravel's `vendor` folder became over `100MB`, but most of the space is taken by `doctrine`'s `.git` folder. During the upload to staging/production server, I noticed some files are way too big in size.

For example:

```
vendor/doctrine/dbal/.git/objects/pack
     pack-6148870d55dc1aed39190e0c320580376f4983cc.pack (17,000 KB)
```

I checked and at least `60MB` of used storage is caused by `Doctrine's .git` folders alone.

Are they safe to delete? Deployment takes up to two hours due to my low upload speed, so I would like to get rid of anything unnecessary in vendor folder.

Comment: Try running `git gc` in `vendor/doctrine/dbal`. Does the total size of the directory contents shrink?

Comment: @cdhowie Nope. It doesn't.

Comment: You shouldnt deploy `.git` folders. If you use any sane tool for deployment, you can just exclude all `.git` folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use git for version control, they should be safe to delete.
Probably one of the devs uses it locally, and didn't add `.git` to the `.gitignore` file. If you want this gone in the future, you should ask him/her to do that.

Comment: We use Git for version control, but we probably don't need them on production server, so I need a way to skip them during deployment.

Comment: If that's a vendor project, I think it would be safe to delete the .git folder, since you're never interfacing with it directly. It won't affect code functionality at all.